# How to list the contents under a path written a file while opening the same file in vim editor?

Tags: linux, vim

for example, consider the following line to be a sentence in the file that is being edited by vim editor.

set a "/home/Desktop"

Now by placing the cursor at end of path name, is there a key in vim editor to list out the contents in /home/Desktop path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, vim has auto-completion, if your cursor at the end of your path string, in INSERT mode, press `ctrl-x ctrl-f`, you see the popup menu.

for detailed description:

```
:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F
```